# getting Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'. when clean and rebuilt project in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

**Error**:(11) Tag `<uses-permission>` attribute name has invalid character ' '.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
 com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\22.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution

i was using following tag in manifest which causes issue

```html
 <meta-data
  android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" />
```